# How to hide Whatsapp group chat, without leaving it? (Mute and archive don't work.)

Tags: whatsapp

I've tried both the **mute** and **archive** functions. But still, every time there's a new message in the Whatsapp group chat, the green circle thing with a number still shows up to notify me, and the group chat appears near the top. I can also read the first few words of the latest message in that group chat.

Short of leaving the group, is there any way to "truly" mute it? That is, have it completely out of sight and relegated to the bottom of my list of chats, but I can still locate it, look at all the new messages, and respond to it whenever I like?

Comment: There is still not any way to do it in 2020...come on Whatsapp...

Answer (score 12):

As of now there's no such option.

Even if you mute it and archive it, whenever the messages arrive, the Chat will move to the top of the list based on the order of recent messages you receive.

You can only mute notification chime and hide notifications on drawer as of now.

More information here: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567#mute

Comment: Yikes, that is annoying. But thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: Super annoying.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a feature that I suggested over at WhatsApp support channels: a separate "Groups" tab in which all groups are located, by default, or selectively move desired conversations into it. As Saurabh mentioned, there is no way to natively fix this issue.

But if you are into coding and Android development, you can go wild with Xposed and build a module that permanently hides selected groups or moves them into a separate screen. It's not going to be an easy task, however.

Here's a beginner guide: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2709324

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem and I just came up with a semi-solution:
-first, archive the group chat in question

-when new messages appear to the group, do not read the messages, but just archive the chat again (by pressing and holding the conversation, do not tap it but press and hold and choose "archive" when that option appears)

This way, at least you don't have to read the new messages to make the notification go away and to get the group out of sight. For other group members it looks like you haven't read the messages (at least to my best understanding. When I did this and then checked the archived group chat, it shows to me that I did not read the new messages).

Comment: So I have 10 groups very active but currently, I cannot be bothered to check any of them. My chat list is bloated and I need 20 taps to clear it. Rinse and repeat.